# What is a search problem?

Tags: search-algorithms, search

I'm looking for a formal and broad definition.

Intuitively, I would say that a problem where various checks have to be done is a search problem. Is this the only criteria? How can we know that a problem requires multiple checks?

Alternatively, I also think intuitively of problems with multiple paths as a search problem. In this case, only a single check might be necessary but multiple comparisons are needed in order to know which path is the best to follow.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_problem

Comment: Thanks for the link, but it is a poorly written. For example, it uses the symbol  Γ without explaining its meaning. I went to the Turing Machine article but couldn't find that symbol in the whole article.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A problem is a *search problem* if there's an algorithmic way to verify the answer.  In particular, let $V$ be any algorithm that takes two inputs and always terminates.  Then the following is a search problem:

*Input:* $x$
*Goal:* find and output any $y$ such that $V(x,y)=1$, or report that no such $y$ exists

Every search problem can be written in this form.  In particular, you can take the above as the definition of a search problem: a problem is a search problem if there exists an always-terminating algorithm $V$ that has the above form.

Comment: Note that technically any problem can be defined as a search problem. E.g. a decision problem can be defined as $V(x, 0) = 1$ when $x$ is a false instance and $V(x, 1) = 1$ when $x$ is a true instance.  But this is contrived, you should apply common sense when determining what kind of problem something is.